# Ionic 2: unit test for component with ionic's markup/elements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a simple Angular 2 component for an Ionic 2 app. The component uses some Ionic's markup, such as:

```
<ion-card>
    <h3>{{ rawcontent.name }}</h3>
    <p *ngIf="rawcontent.description">{{ rawcontent.description }}</p>
</ion-card>
```

the component .ts is something like:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular/';
import { Content } from '../../pages/content/content';

@Component({
  selector: 'content-detail',
  templateUrl: 'content-detail.html'
})
export class ContentDetailComponent {

  @Input('data') rawcontent: any = {};

  constructor(public nav: NavController) {
  }
  //other methods
}
```

I'm trying to write an unit test for it, but I got this error so far:

> 'ion-card' is not a known element:
>       1. If 'ion-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>       2. If 'ion-card' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.

I don't know what to do now. In this case, ion-card is an Angular component, I guess. So, what to do next? I think I have to change my beforeEach, addining some config. Can anyone help?

```
beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ ContentDetailComponent ],
    providers: [
        { provide: NavController, useClass: NavMock }
    ]})
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `ionicModule`. Add this in `configureTestingModule`

```
  imports: [
  IonicModule,
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good starting blog for testing [Ionic 2 apps](https://www.joshmorony.com/introduction-to-testing-ionic-2-applications-with-testbed/).

You need to configure the app with Ionic module root in `beforeEach`:

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({

            declarations: [MyApp]

            providers: [

            ],

            imports: [
                IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
            ]

        }).compileComponents();

    }));
```